# express post & delete responses concepts not understood

Tags: javascript, express

I have no clue, but it seems that when I try to get into an attribute of an element from the JSON file it says that it's null.
Still got npm audit problems :(, what do you think about that?

**Here is the EDITED code that I did so far:**

```
export const data = require('./file.json');
export let DATA = data as Type[]; 

let temp = DATA;

app.post('/api/tickets', (req, res) => {
    // load past data into json string
    const past_data = JSON.stringify(temp);
    // load new data into json string
    const new_element = JSON.stringify(req.params.formData)
    if (new_element !== "")
    {
        // concat both string to 1 json string, then write into fs
        fs.writeFile("./file.json",[past_data,new_element],(err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }

    // send it back as response to request
    const new_data = JSON.parse([past_data,new_element].toString());
    res.send(new_data);
});

app.delete('/api/tickets/:id', (req,res) => {
    // fined requested ticket based on id in global temp
    const ticket = temp.find(t => t.id === (req.params.id));
    if (typeof ticket !== 'undefined') {
        const index = temp.indexOf(ticket);
        // remove it from global temp
        temp.splice(index, 1)
    }

    // create json string out of global temp
    const data_after_delete = JSON.stringify(temp);

    // write it straight into fs
    fs.writeFile("./file.json",data_after_delete,(err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    // send it back to requester
    const new_data = JSON.parse(data_after_delete);
    res.send(new_data);
});
```

**One object from the json file before I write into it:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "81a885d6-8f68-5bc0-bbbc-1c7b32e4b4e4",
    "title": "Need a Little Help with Your Site? Hire a Corvid Web Developer",
    "content": "Here at Wix we strive to support you with this community forum, API references, articles, videos and code examples. But sometimes you might need a little extra help to get your site exactly the way you want it. \nHire a developer from the Wix Arena, an online marketplace with top Corvid web developers from around the world. Submit your project details here, and we’ll find the right professional for you.",
    "userEmail": "jug@nesetal.af",
    "creationTime": 1542111235544,
    "labels": ["Corvid", "Api"]
  },
```

**One object from the json file after I write into it:**

```
["[\"[\\\"[\\\\\\\"[{\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"81a885d6-8f68-5bc0-bbbc-1c7b32e4b4e4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"title\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Need a Little Help with Your Site? Hire a Corvid Web Developer\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"content\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Here at Wix we strive to support you with this community forum, API references, articles, videos and code examples. But sometimes you might need a little extra help to get your site exactly the way you want it. \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\nHire a developer from the Wix Arena, an online marketplace with top Corvid web developers from around the world. Submit your project details here, and we’ll find the right professional for you.\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"userEmail\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"jug@nesetal.af\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"creationTime\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":1542111235544,\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"labels\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\":[\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Corvid\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\",\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"Api\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"]},
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure of your exact problem, I think **a** problem here is that you're reading `data.json` with a require statement. I think this would more-or-less cache the result in memory, and everytime you call `JSON.strinfigy(data)` in your post route, you're using the in-memory version of `data.json` as opposed to the value you're writing to the disk. At least until you restart the entire process, that is.

Comment: As @khauri said - require will cache things, so it probably won't do what you expect it to. You have to read and write using fs.

Comment: what cache means in this manner? it won't update data even after I write with fs on post and delete beforehand?

Comment: @HarelYacovian It will update the data onto the file on disk. But the way `require` works is once you have read the `data.json` in `data` the first time it is **cached** (sort of stored in memory) so every time you would access it ..it would return you the very first loaded result and not the actual that exists on disk.

Comment: in my get response, I do a read file into temp variable which is being declared on a global scope and is used later on post and delete correspondingly.

Comment: Where and how is `temp` declared? Please show that in your code.

Comment: No problem, I've checked and it seems I'm not writing it as it should be. the JSON structure is damaged. (pictures attached)

Comment: `JSON.parse([past_data,new_element].toString())` makes no sense, I doubt that works.

Comment: Still got a problem with type matching - I've attached pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `JSON.stringify` when writing to a file, and `JSON.parse` when reading from a file (if you don't use `require` which does the parsing implicitly). Manipulate your data as plain objects and arrays, not as JSON strings - that will only damage the structure as you noticed.

```
export let DATA: Type[] = require('./file.json');
function save() {
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(DATA);
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ only call it here
    fs.writeFile("./file.json", jsonString, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
}

app.post('/api/tickets', (req, res) => {
    if (req.params.formData) {
        const new_element = req.params.formData; // might need a JSON.parse() if it's a a json string
        // add to global temp by array manipulation
        DATA.push(new_element);
        save();
    }
    // send it back as response to request
    res.send(DATA);
});

app.delete('/api/tickets/:id', (req,res) => {
    // find requested ticket based on id in global temp
    const ticket = DATA.findIndex(t => t.id === (req.params.id));
    if (ticket !== -1) {
        // remove it from global temp
        DATA.splice(index, 1);
        save();
    }
    // send it back to requester
    res.send(DATA);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I'm checking it now, about post, formData is an object, thus I dont need parse it right?